# Jquery popup pass selected checkbox values to Parent window not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Friends

Im writing a jsp that opens a pop-up window using jQuery that has checkboxs and a user can then select all checkbox values on a pop-up window and then on Submit , it gets displayed to the parent window,
So far I am able to open up a pop-up on click that displays the list of checkboxes and Im struggling to send the checked checkbox values to the parent page , Please suggest

My code is

```
<form action= "" id ="overlay_form" method= "post" style="display:none">
        <h3>Select Language</h3> 
        <br /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="English" /> English  <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="French" /> French  <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="Norwagian" /> Norwagian  <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="Swedish" /> Swedish <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="Chinese" /> Chinese <br/>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="row-fluid grid-footer">
        <div class="span8"></div>
        <div class="span5">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-primary-secondary" type="submit" name="saveDepartmentBtn" id="saveOrg" value="Save" onclick="this.disabled='disabled'; document.getElementById('saveOrg').disabled='disable';this.form.submit(); ">
          </div>
          <div class="span1">
        <button  class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" cancel-action="/admin/role/list" ><spring:message code="common.cancel" /></button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
<p id="text">
                Selected Languages are: 
            </p>
```

Now to send the checked checkboxes data to the parent my JQuery code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#overlay_form').submit(function(){

                    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                        window.parent.$("#text").text(parent.$("#text").text() + $(this).val()+" ,");

                    });
                    parent.$.close();
                    return false;
        });             
    });
```

However Send the selected checkboxes data to the Parent window is not working
Please advice

Comment: Are you opening an actual popup, i.e. `window.open`?  Just asking because the form name is `overlay` and that usually means a "popup" like a modal div.

Comment: yes, the pop-up gets opened up but Im unable to send the checked values to the parents window

Comment: <style>
#overlay_form{
position: absolute;
border: 5px solid gray;
padding: 10px;
background: white;
width: 270px;
height: 380px;
}
#pop{
display: block;
border: 1px solid gray;
width: 65px;
text-align: center;
padding: 6px;
border-radius: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>

Comment: How are you *opening* this popup?  More and more makes me think it's not `window.open` and it's more of a div overlay.  Show me the code that opens your popup.

Comment: here is my code to open the pop-up 
$(document).ready(function(){
 //open popup
 $("#pop").click(function(){
 $("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
 positionPopup();
 });
  
 //close popup
 $("#close").click(function(){
 $("#overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
 });
 });

Comment: Ok that's what I thought. I submitted an answer.

Comment: I modified my code further as 
  $('#saveOrg').click(function(){
               $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                 window.parent.$("#text").text(parent.$("#text").text() + $(this).val()+" ,");
                });
                parent.$.colorbox.close();
               return true;
    });
Now the value gets displayed to  Selected Languages are: 
However the page gets reloaded and value disappers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually creating a real window.  It's an overlay.  So it's not a popup, it's not a window, and thus there is no `window.parent` for what you're working in.

Instead you have a hidden div / form that gets shown and positioned overtop of your window.  Since this is all done with CSS and Javascript, there is no `parent` to your form because it's in the same window as the rest of your markup.

I'm sure if you looked at the javascript console of your browser you'd see an error along the lines of `window.parent is null / not an object`.

There's the explanation.  Here's the answer: remove `window.parent` and `parent` from your code.  And since it's not a window, you're not `closing` a window, so your `close` is likely a `fadeOut`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#overlay_form').submit(function(){

                $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                    $("#text").text($("#text").text() + $(this).val()+ " ,");

                });
                $('#overlay_form').fadeOut(500);

                return false;
    });             
});
```

Comment: Thanks , I need your thoughts on one more catch that is 
I modified my code further as
 $('#saveOrg').click(function(){ $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){ window.parent.$("#text").text(parent.$("#text").text() + $(this).val()+" ,"); }); 
parent.$.colorbox.close();
 return true; }); Now the value gets displayed to Selected Languages are: However the page gets reloaded and value disappears

Comment: It gets reloaded because your code is invalid, it's throwing a javascript error `on submit`, and your `return false;` is not getting executed which means the form is doing an actual submit (post / refresh).  Look at your JS error console in your browser.  Change your function to what I have instead of what you're attempting, then work from what I have up to what you want.  As you encounter more errors, post more questions.  But I think what you're asking for now is completely different and shouldn't be a part of this question.

Comment: Thanks Eli :)
your answer is appreciated :)